# Guess count display error for java

Tags: java

i tried to display the amount of times the user has guessed and these are the **errors** :

> NumberGame.java:44: not a statement
>         System.out.println{"Number of guesses: " + guessCount);
>                   ^ NumberGame.java:44: ';' expected
>         System.out.println{"Number of guesses: " + guessCount);
>                           ^ NumberGame.java:44: not a statement
>         System.out.println{"Number of guesses: " + guessCount);
>                                                  ^ NumberGame.java:44: ';' expected
>         System.out.println{"Number of guesses: " + guessCount);
>                                                              ^ NumberGame.java:48: reached end of file while parsing }

**my code is:**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberGame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int MAX_NUMER = 100;

      int number = rand.nextInt(MAX_NUMBER) + 1;
        int on_off = 1;
      int guessCount = 0;
      int guess; 


      Random rand = new Random();
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(on_off == 1)
      {
            System.out.print("Guess a number between 1 and 100: ");
         guess = keyboard.nextInt();
         guessCount++;

            if(guess < number)
         {

            System.out.println("Too Low");
            guessCount++;
            }

            if(guess > number)
         {

            System.out.println("Too High");
            guessCount++;
            }

            if(guess == number)
         {

            System.out.println("Correct! You win!");
            }

        }
         System.out.println{"Number of guesses: " + guessCount};

    }
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks for your time!

Comment: The error say it all. You have an opening brace intead of bracket in `System.out.println{"Number of guesses: " + guessCount);`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo. Unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: You have three problems with your code. `System.out.println` is a function, so you use parenthesis like so: `System.out.println("Hello world!")`. You mistyped `MAX_NUMBER` in line 8. You also need to declare and initialize `rand` before you first use it. Look at my answer to see code that compiles, and a bit more detail.

Comment: @madth3 False, it is about a conceptual misunderstanding about the usage of `{}` and `()`.  It can help beginners who may have a similar misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your corrected syntax seems to have replaced the closing parenthesis, `)`, with a closing curly brace, `}`.

Here I replaced the `{` with a `(` in line 44. Also, I fixed a typo in line 8 where you wrote `MAX_NUMER` instead of `MAX_NUMBER`. Also, `rand` needs to be declared and initialized before it first gets used, so I moved it up above where you assign `number` a value.

For the first error, a method call uses parenthesis, not curly braces; curly braces are used for blocks of code, like code within a class, or for the body of a method.

The second error is just a typo, and is rather uninteresting.

The third error with not declaring and initializing rand is just that; You need to declare a variable before it can be used, and for Random it needs to be initialized before it can first be used.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberGame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int MAX_NUMBER = 100;

        Random rand = new Random();

        int number = rand.nextInt(MAX_NUMBER) + 1;
        int on_off = 1;
        int guessCount = 0;
        int guess; 

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(on_off == 1)
        {
            System.out.print("Guess a number between 1 and 100: ");
            guess = keyboard.nextInt();
            guessCount++;

            if(guess < number)
            {
                System.out.println("Too Low");
                guessCount++;
            }

            if(guess > number)
            {
                System.out.println("Too High");
                guessCount++;
            }

            if(guess == number)
            {
                System.out.println("Correct! You win!");
            }
            System.out.println("Number of guesses: " + guessCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 System.out.println{"Number of guesses: " + guessCount);
```

should be

```
 System.out.println("Number of guesses: " + guessCount);
```

You have a typo there. you wrote `{`  instead of `(`

And in the line

```
 int number = rand.nextInt(MAX_NUMBER) + 1;
```

You haven't declared `rand`

And

int number = rand.nextInt(MAX_NUMBER) + 1;

should be

```
 int number = rand.nextInt(MAX_NUMER) + 1; //you decalred final int MAX_NUMER
```

PS :I'm suggesting you to use IDE,which saves you a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error.  Look at your line carefully.  You have a `{` instead of a `(`.

```
System.out.println{"Number of guesses: " + guessCount);
```

You have mismatched brackets.

**Further explanation based on your comment:**

Curly braces `{}` usually signify a code block, something you can do to group code as a sort of singular statement, in a very simplified sense (i.e. `if (x==1) {statements;} else { more statements;}`).

Parentheses `()` can be used as part of functions.  In your case, `System.out.println` is a function that is given to you to use.  Inside the `()`, you pass arguments/parameters.  In this case, you are passing the String you want Java to print out.  For your `System.out.println()`, you want parentheses, not curly braces.

Comment: I have already edited my code but still says its not a statement and a `;` is expected during this code `System.out.println{"Number of guesses: " + guessCount);`

Comment: System.out.println is a function.  As such, according to the language syntax, it uses `()`, **not** `{}`.  `{}` is appropriate for code blocks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in your code:

```
System.out.println{"Number of guesses: " + guessCount);
```

The opening parenthesis is wrong. It should be:

```
System.out.println("Number of guesses: " + guessCount);
```

Also there is typo in the variable name:

```
final int MAX_NUMER = 100;
```

It should be

```
final int MAX_NUMBER = 100;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Use `(` indstead of `{`  brace in the `println`